# Create anonymous instance of interface

Tags: vb.net, interface, anonymous-class

I am new to vb.net and have an function which takes an typed interface and I want to create an anonymous instance of the interface as the method argument.

### Interface

```
Public Interface MessageHandler(Of T)

    Sub Handle(Message As T)

End Interface
```

---

I am not sure if I descripted my problem correctly so here is what i want in Java:

### Interface

```
public interface MessageHandler<T> {

    public abstract void handle(T message);

}
```

### Method call

```
function(new MessageHandler<Type>() {

    public void handle(Type message) {
        //Do Something
    }

});
```

Comment: If you know java why not go with C# rather than VB.NET?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't create anonymous implementations of interfaces in .NET. You have to have a concrete implementation, but you can hide it an give the same kind of anonymization easily enough.

I've .NET-ified your naming conventions, but here it is:

```
Public Interface IMessageHandler(Of T)
    Sub Handle(message As T)
End Interface

Public NotInheritable Class MessageHandler
    Private Sub New()
    End Sub
    Private Class AnonymousMessageHandler(Of T)
        Implements IMessageHandler(Of T)
        Private _handler As Action(Of T)
        Public Sub New(handler As Action(Of T))
            _handler = handler
        End Sub
        Public Sub Handle(message As T) Implements IMessageHandler(Of T).Handle
            Dim h = _handler
            If h IsNot Nothing Then
                h(message)
            End If
        End Sub
    End Class

    Public Shared Function Create(Of T)(handler As Action(Of T)) As IMessageHandler(Of T)
        Return New AnonymousMessageHandler(Of T)(handler)
    End Function
End Class
```

Or, in C#:

```
public interface IMessageHandler<T>
{
    void Handle(T message);
}

public static class MessageHandler
{
    private class AnonymousMessageHandler<T> : IMessageHandler<T>
    {
        private Action<T> _handler;
        public AnonymousMessageHandler(Action<T> handler)
        {
            _handler = handler;
        }
        public void Handle(T message)
        {
            _handler?.Invoke(message);
        }
    }

    public static IMessageHandler<T> Create<T>(Action<T> handler)
    {
        return new AnonymousMessageHandler<T>(handler);
    }
}
```

You can call it (in VB.NET) like this:

```
MessageHandler.Create(Of Integer)(Sub (x) Console.WriteLine(x)).Handle(42)
```